# xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, azure-pipelines

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services to build my app. When I try to run unit tests, I'm getting an error:

```
xcodebuild: error: option 'Destination' requires at least one parameter of the form 'key=value'
```

This started after upgrading to Xcode 8.3. The build server has 8.3, but when I run unit tests it wants to use the 8.2 simulator. This fails.

When I try to specify the 8.3 simulator explicitly, using the `-destination` switch, it fails.

```
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (9.7 inch),OS=10.3"
```

I've also tried using apostrophes ' around the destination, no quotes or apostrophes, and simulator IDs, but nothing helps. Without quotes, I get this error:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action 'Pro'.
```

Comment: What's the result if you run xcodebuild command on build agent manually? What's the result call xctool?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the build machine, but I can ask a coworker to try it tomorrow.

Comment: Feel free to post the result here. On the other hand, what's detail setting of XCode Test step? What's the detail build log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake! I was trying to put the `-destination` parameter in the Actions box, like this:

[image]

I didn't see the Arguments box under Advanced. 
When I put this parameter there, it works!

[image]

What was odd is that it accepted and tried to use the -destination parameter in the Actions box.

Seems this should be disallowed, or if allowed, handled the same way as when it is in the Arguments box.

Thanks to madhurig on GitHub for her [reply](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1051#issuecomment-302212839) to my question, which clued me in to my mistake.

Comment: Can you please share a full snippet of the xCode test task? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I don't have this pipeline anymore.

Answer (score 10):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes, like so:

```
-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Pro (9.7 inch),OS=10.3"
```

That fixed the same problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

**Single quotes** with **Equal separator** works in form of `'key=value'`, as:

```
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=12.1,name=iPhone X'
```

To get the list of **Known Devices** use:

```
instruments -s devices
```

Answer (score 1):

Landed here looking for a resolution for the same error. As as addendum, you can also pass a single key=val to -destination e.g `-destination 'platform=iOS'` and xcodebuild will tell you all the alternative available for the scheme.

```
λ ~/Development/app-ios/ task/JIOS-400-Earl-Grey-Spike* xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme app -destination 'platform=iOS'  -derivedDataPath "build" build-for-testing

User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/schoudhary/Development/app-ios/build

xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS }

    Missing required device specifier option.
    The device type “Generic iOS Device” requires that either “name” or “id” be specified.
    Please supply either “name” or “id”.

    Available destinations for the "App" scheme:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D248DB01-A852-4360-A9C0-2D71AFE478D7, OS:10.3, name:iPad Air }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CE87AF5A-141C-43DA-AE61-AF53593F37F7, OS:10.3, name:iPad Air 2 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E93B43E4-D24E-4927-B9EE-0375E15DCBD5, OS:10.3, name:iPad Pro (9.7 inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D71DB17-0FE2-4D5E-BEE6-CC696445BA11, OS:10.3, name:iPad Pro (12.9 inch) }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F7E37EF4-5E72-438A-A286-216C20158B47, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 5 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:24653844-AE99-4B5B-8332-9FFD2208172F, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 5s }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FD2089A4-BF3F-4F98-8E33-B7EFDCFE5B4D, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6EF0DFBD-E99E-4EB3-9C51-6E749F41B6E7, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:846E631C-6285-4B91-9BA6-1AB6E66C88DB, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6s }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A6943ADC-F6EF-42F6-9958-D966DFC419FC, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B41ABED0-7554-438A-97AC-F34943ED4D79, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 7 }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:20F1582C-0D19-4F42-9DAD-43138FB923B9, OS:10.3, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:683BB5CA-E0A8-4CE4-B0DD-AED4C4295B90, OS:10.3, name:iPhone SE }

    Ineligible destinations for the "App" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }
```

just another useful way to get the right destination.

Comment: Update: In my case just using the id did the trick,
`xcodebuild  -workspace app.xcworkspace -scheme appTests -destination ‘id=FD2089A4-BF3F-4F98-8E33-B7EFDCFE5B4D’  -derivedDataPath "build" build-for-testing `

Comment: i know i'm late to the party but.. `xcodebuild -workspace myWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme myScheme -configuration Debug -showdestinations`
just another useful way to get the right destination. 

Answer (score 0):

For XCode Version 13.2.1, try the below command:

```
xcodebuild clean build -scheme App -project App.xcodeproj -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=15.2,name=iPhone 13 Pro'
```

Where:
App is the scheme name and App.xcodeproj is the App name.